# Create Project with Angular 4 Release using Angular CLI

Tags: angular, angular-cli

How do I create new project with the latest Angular 4 release using Angular CLI with the command below :

> ng new new_project

I have the following versions installed

```
 - @angular/cli: 1.0.0-rc.2
 - node: 7.7.3
 - npm: 4.4.1
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

<strike>You cannot create a new Angular application with the CLI that uses Angular 4 out of the box. At least, not at the moment. Only Angular 2 is supported by the CLI, at this time. I imagine that will change soon enough.</strike>

However, you can create a new application using `ng new <app-name>`, and then change the version of Angular it uses in the package.json. Run `npm install`, and it should all work. That has been my experience.

Hope this helps you out.

**UPDATE:**

I am mistaken! There is an option that you can pass to the `ng new` command that will set up the project to use ng 4.

`ng new project_new --ng4`

From `ng --help`:

`--ng4 (Boolean) (Default: false) Create a project with Angular 4 in the template.`

Right now this sets up the @angular section package.json as follows.

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": ">=4.0.0-beta <5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": ">=4.0.0-beta <5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": ">=4.0.0-beta <5.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": ">=4.0.0-beta <5.0.0",
    "@angular/http": ">=4.0.0-beta <5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": ">=4.0.0-beta <5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": ">=4.0.0-beta <5.0.0",
    "@angular/router": ">=4.0.0-beta <5.0.0",
    ...
```

Just tried it, and it works.

**UPDATE 2**

The `--ng4` option has now been removed as the *latest* CLI will now create an Angular 5 project just by using `ng new project_name`.

Comment: Finding out if what this link says is true https://twitter.com/ladyleet/status/841074080342134785

Comment: Twitter is blocked where I am at, and I couldn't be more pleased about it. :)

Comment: Was under #Angular4 and I quote " you gen a new angular app with angularcli it gives you an #angular4 app. No more updating package.json" Seeing if I can get anything.

Comment: I agree with you answer updating "package.json" Just what to find out if its possible with angularcli.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I had actually done that and got 4.0 beta verison. Latest version is 4.0.0-rc.3 and still your answer is correct. Just thought the current CLI would pick it by default that is the Latest version is 4.0.0-rc.3

Comment: Well, that `package.json` is using a range for the @angular version. So, it is pulling the latest (up to version 5). What I ran pulled v4.0.0-rc.3. This is doing what you would like.

Answer (score 17):

The ***easiest*** way to create an Angular 4  project using Angular CLI is install an older version of the @angular/cli (1.4.10)

```
npx @angular/cli@1.4.10 new myangular4
```

(thanks [Explosion Pills](https://stackoverflow.com/users/454533/explosion-pills))

Or

```
> npm remove -g @angular/cli
> npm install -g @angular/cli@1.4.10
> ng --version
  @angular/cli: 1.4.10
> ng new myangular4
```

Creates a myangular4/package.json

```
{
  "name": "myangular4",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/http": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "^4.2.4",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
```

Comment: This approach worked for me, except that I had to use version v1.4.10 (npm install -g @angular/cli@1.4.10).

A colleague directed me to version 1.4.10 after he encountered  the issue described here (https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9303) and applied the recommended solution.

Comment: I encountered the same error as comment above when running "ng new my-ng-project". Runned "npm remove -g @angular/cli" and "npm install -g @angular/cli@1.4.10" to get it working.

Comment: Thanks @EricBowden and Ivan. I have updated my answer.

Comment: It may be even easier to do `npx @angular/cli@1.4.10 new myangular4`

Answer (score 3):

Update your angular-cli version, then try to use "ng new new_project" command to create new angular 4 application.

Comment: Currently this should work. This question was just before the Angular 4 release was done. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I had ng already installed a long time ago (about 4 months, but a *very long time* in Angular terms). Doing a `npm install -g @angular/cli` didn't do the job.

I had to `npm install -g @angular/cli --upgrade` to update the cli.

Then doing `ng new myProject --mobile` got me the >4 Angular

Comment: Currently this should work. This question was just before the Angular 4 release was done. Thanks. –

Answer (score 3):

To create an Angular_4 project using Angular CLI follow these commands lines :

> > npm remove -g @angular/cli
> >
> > npm install -g @angular/cli@1.4.10
> >
> > ng new myNewAngular4App

Comment: these steps worked for me to downgrade Angular 5 to 4

Comment: @SuriyaRakhunathan I am glad it help you

Comment: Finally found the downgrade for @angular/cli, many thanks @BlaCkHoLe

Answer (score 1):

The answers above are correct. However, if you have an open angular project, say on VS code you may need to take a few different steps.

1. Install [Node.js® and npm](https://nodejs.org/en/) if they are not already on your machine.
2. Then install the Angular CLI globally: 
   **`npm install -g @angular/cli`**
3. Inside the VS code terminal run: **`npm install`**
4. (Inside the VS code terminal) serve the application: **`ng serve --open`**

Answer (score 1):

You should check your latest Angular CLI version :

> ng -v

If you need to install/update your version just run

> sudo npm install -g @angular/cli@latest

Then you can create project with comand

> ng new Project_Name

There are few more options , just FYI

> ng new Project_Name --style=scss

Now this will create new project named "Project_Name"

```
"dependencies": {
  "@angular/animations": "^4.2.4",
  "@angular/common": "^4.2.4",
  "@angular/compiler": "^4.2.4",
  "@angular/core":  "^4.2.4",
  "@angular/forms": "^4.2.4",
  "@angular/http": "^4.2.4",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.2.4",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.2.4",
  "@angular/router": "^4.2.4"
}
```

If you want to update any packages you can update by command

> npm install @angular/{{package_name}} // E.g. npm install @angular/core

Answer (score 0):

I do it as indicated by the official [documentation of Angular](https://angular.io/guide/quickstart)

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
ng new your-app
cd your-app
ng serve --open
```

open your browser on http://localhost:4200/

Comment: oh look an angular 3 app... :(

Answer (score 0):

1. In my case i updated the package.json i set the version of all the packages begin with @angular to 4.x.x  except angular/cli ( i.e : @angular/animations": "4.x.x") which means import the latest version of the version 4 (which is 4.4.6).
2. then i executed npm install.
3. to verify the installed version execute : npm list --depth=0 | grep angular
4. this is a part of the updated package.json :

   `"dependencies": {
           "@angular/animations": "4.x.x",
           "@angular/common": "4.x.x",
           "@angular/compiler": "4.x.x",
           "@angular/core": "4.x.x",
           "@angular/forms": "4.x.x",
           "@angular/http": "4.x.x",
           "@angular/platform-browser": "4.x.x",
           "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.x.x",
           "@angular/platform-server": "4.x.x",
           "@angular/router": "4.x.x",
           "@ngx-translate/core": "^6.0.1",
           "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "0.0.3",
           "@types/form-data": "^2.2.0",
           "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.35",
           "angular2-jwt": "^0.2.2",
           "angular2-text-mask": "^8.0.3",
           "base64-js": "^1.2.1",
           "browser-sync": "^2.23.2",
           "chart.js": "^2.7.0",
           "classlist.js": "1.1.20150312",
           "core-js": "2.4.1",
           "crypto-js": "3.1.9-1",
           "expect": "^1.20.2",
           "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
           "google-libphonenumber": "3.0.3",
           "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
           "intl": "1.2.5",
           "lodash": "4.17.4",
           "moment-timezone": "^0.5.14",
           "ng2-page-scroll": "4.0.0-beta.7",
           "pako": "^1.0.6",
           "pdfjs-dist": "^1.8.398",
           "rxjs": "^5.4.2",
           "url-search-params-polyfill": "^2.0.1",
           "vls-web-modules": "0.0.21",
           "web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
           "zone.js": "0.8.4"
         },
         "devDependencies": {
           "@angular/cli": "1.6.5",
           "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.x.x",
           "@angular/platform-server": "4.x.x",
           "@angularclass/hmr": "^2.1.3",
           "@compodoc/compodoc": "^1.0.1",
           "@types/globalize": "0.0.31",
           "@types/googlemaps": "^3.30.0",
           "@types/jasmine": "^2.8.3",
           "@types/node": "^6.0.88",
           "@vls-web-modules/zuul-binder": "0.0.11",
           "codelyzer": "^2.0.1",
           "enhanced-resolve": "3.3.0",
           "immutable": "^3.8.1",
           "jasmine-core": "2.8.0",
           "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
           "karma": "~1.4.1",
           "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
           "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
           "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "0.2.0",
           "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
           "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "0.2.2",
           "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.4",
           "protractor": "~5.1.0",
           "release-it": "2.7.3",
           "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
           "tslint": "~4.5.0",
           "typedoc": "0.6.0",
           "typescript": "2.4",
           "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.9.0"
         }`

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1.** Set up the Development Environment: 
 Install **Node.js** and **npm** if they are not installed.

**Step 2:**  Then install the **Angular CLI** globally.

**`npm install -g @angular/cli@1.4.*`**

**Step 3:** Create a new project

**`ng new my-app`**

**Step 4:** run the application:

**`cd my-app`**

**`ng serve --open`**

The above app will be in angular 4.